# Was Haile Selassie the world's only involuntary messiah?

Tags: religion, religious-history, individuals

History is full of [supposed Messiahs and Saviors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_messiah_claimants) who founded religious movements and/or identified themselves as saviors (e.g. Joseph Smith and Raël). (By contrast, some messiahs were only venerated posthumously, possibly obscuring their actual wishes and intentions.)

[Haile Selassie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haile_Selassie) is a possibly unique example of an involuntary living messiah. [Rastafarians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rastafari) considered his ascension to the Ethiopian throne to fulfill predictions of Marcus Garvey and the Book of Daniel. Selassie treated his unorthodox adherents respectfully, meeting them when he [visited Jamaica in 1966](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grounation_Day) and allowing some to move to Ethiopia. He arranged to send an [Ethiopian Orthodox mission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abuna_Yesehaq) to Jamaica and had no direct involvement in the Rastafarian movement.

Did anyone else happen to find themselves identified as a messiah for *thousands of believers* during their lifetime? Of course, a similar story was the premise of the comedy film ["Life of Brian"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Python%27s_Life_of_Brian). Let's exclude quasi-religious subjection in the form of the [divine right of kings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divine_right_of_kings) or [celebrity worship syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celebrity_worship_syndrome).

**Or was Haile Selassie the world's only involuntary messiah?**

[image: H.I.M.]

Comment: I instantly thought of Life Of Brian too...

Comment: While maybe not truly a messiah, where do your question stand on the Dalai Lama reincarnations? Is this applicable as Tibetan Buddhists acknowledge that you cannot _will_ yourself to incarnate as the reincarnated DL?

Comment: _"Let's exclude quasi-religious subjection in the form of the divine right of kings or celebrity worship syndrome"_ I think this is overly restrictive. How do you expect an unwilling messiah to spawn a religion, if not by either pre-existing authority (right of kings) or popular support (celebrity)? The involuntary nature of the messiah inherently suggests that _others_ attribute messiah-ness to this person, thus inherently making them a celebrity.

Comment: @Flater I think you're party right, in that there is a line that gets crossed somewhere where it's no longer quite so "quasi".  Unfortunately everyone will see a different line.

Comment: @Spencer: I agree and I'm afraid this otherwise interesting question is going to be damned either way because of it. Without the restriction it's a subjective argument of what separates a messiah from a celebrity (inherently leading to a discussion of what a religion is), with the _full_ restriction it makes the question unanswerable, and with a more _balanced_ restriction it turns into an argument on where to strike that balance.

Comment: @Flater I agree that fame is involved, but CWS is a mental disorder afflicting individuals and not religious in nature.

Comment: @AaronBrick But that doesn't exclude that CWS in a large group of people _spawns_ what will become a genuine religion. Satirical as it may be, Life of Brian is not that impossible either.

Comment: @jwenting Yes. Mandatory xkcd, er, Monty Python: [I'm not the messiah!](https://youtu.be/64KlhfIN5qY)

Comment: @Flater Maybe, but this is pretty hypothetical. I haven't seen any examples of CWS among a large group, nor of a religious style of CWS.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica you're just a very naughty boy!

Comment: @LangLangC: however controversial IMO you should undelete your answer.

Comment: Not by 'thousands of believers' but there is a tribe in Vanautu who worships [Prince Philip.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_Philip_Movement)

Answer (score 4):

[Jiddu Krishnamurti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jiddu_Krishnamurti) was believed to be a sort of messiah (the 'World Teacher') by the Theosophists. In the 1920s he disavowed this idea and dissolved the organisation that had been established to support it.

Answer (score 3):

Another movement with an involuntary divinity - not exactly a Messiah - is [Prince Philip Movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_Philip_Movement). Some people in a village in Vanuatu seem to believe that the Duke of Edinburgh is a divine being.

Comment: My first impression on reading this answer was..."Wasn't that where they had the cargo cult?" (...reads link...). "Ha!"

Answer (score 2):

You are asking about people who were regarded literally as "the Messiah", not as a "saviour" or "divinity", right? Then we need to mention the late Lubavitcher Rebbe, Menachem Schneerson, whose followers regarded him as the Messiah, a claim which he rejected. An involuntary Messiah.

Comment: Who regarded him as the Messiah, and when did he reject it?

Comment: @Alex. This is well-known, I think. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chabad_messianism